# JavaFX : remove a component from the component itself

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple JavaFX application with main controller. In this main controller I dynamically add this component :

Added component:

[image: Added component]

FXML code of this component (paramValue.fxml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="833.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demoSpreadsSheet.ParamValueController">
   <children>
      <Label prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Paramètre : " />
      <TextField fx:id="paramName" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
      <Label prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="83.0" text="Valeur : ">
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="40.0" />
         </HBox.margin>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="paramValue" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="12.0">
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </HBox.margin>
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="21.0" onMouseClicked="#openSpreadSheet" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../Images/spreadsheet.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </Button>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removeParamValue" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="12.0">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="21.0" onMouseClicked="#openSpreadSheet" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../../Images/remove.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
         <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" />
         </HBox.margin>
      </Button>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Controller of the component :

```
package com.example.demoSpreadsSheet;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class ParamValueController extends HBox {

    @FXML TextField paramName, paramValue;

    public ParamValueController() {}

    @FXML
    public void openSpreadSheet(){

    }

    @FXML
    private void removeParamValue(){
        //I don't know if it's possible to remove it here
    }




}
```

The controller where I add my custom component :

```
package com.example.demoSpreadsSheet;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DoublonController extends BorderPane {

    @FXML VBox paramValueList;

    public DoublonController(){}

    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        paramValueList.getChildren().addAll(createParamValueComponent(), createParamValueComponent());
    }

    private HBox createParamValueComponent() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader paramValueLoader = new FXMLLoader(DoublonController.class.getResource("paramValue.fxml"));
        return paramValueLoader.load();
    }

    @FXML
    private void addParamValue() throws IOException {
        this.paramValueList.getChildren().add(createParamValueComponent());
    }
}
```

I want to remove this component when the user click on the red cross. The problem is that the redcross calls the function "removeParamValue()" within the class that I want to remove which i think is impossible..

Do you have a workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with paramValue.getParent().getChildren().remove(paramValue)? (modulo type check against parent)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two approaches you can use.

---

## Get the `Parent`

As mentioned by @kleopatra in [a question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613592/javafx-remove-a-component-from-the-component-itself#comment128268527_72613592), you can get the parent of the root FXML node from within the "child" controller, check if it is an instance of `Pane` and, if it is, then modify the parent's children list.
For example:

```java
@FXML
private void removeParamValue() {
    var parent = container.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof Pane pane) {
        pane.getChildren().remove(container);
    }
}
```

This requires you to inject the root FXML element into the controller. I made the name of the field `container`, whose type would be `HBox`, but you can name it anything you'd like (just make sure add the corresponding `fx:id` attribute to the FXML file). I also made use of [pattern matching for `instanceof`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394), which was finalized in Java 16. If you are not using at least Java 16, then you'll need to manually cast `parent` to a `Pane`.

### Problem With Your Code

Note you can't use `this.getParent()`, because the controller itself has never been added to the scene graph. In fact, with how your code is currently written, your controller class should not be extending `HBox` at all (and I assume a similar problem with your other controller class). Perhaps you meant to use [`fx:root`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#root_elements), but that would involve changing both the root element of your FXML file and how you load the FXML file. Read the [linked documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#root_elements) for more information.

In other words, unless you want to use `fx:root`, remove the `extends HBox` and `extends BorderPane` from your controller classes.

---

## Use a "Callback"

The other approach is to use a callback. Add a method to your `ParamValueController` which accepts some functional interface (e.g., `Runnable`):

```java
public void setOnRemove(Runnable action) {
    // also declare a field to store the Runnable in
    this.action = action;
}
```

Then your "remove param value" method would look like:

```java
@FXML
private void removeParamValue() {
    if (action != null) {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

And you'd modify the code that loads the "child" FXML like so:

```java
private HBox createParamValueComponent() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader paramValueLoader = new FXMLLoader(DoublonController.class.getResource("paramValue.fxml"));
    HBox root = paramValueLoader.load();
    
    // invoked *after* you load the FXML file
    ParamValueController controller = paramValueLoader.getController();
    controller.setOnRemove(() -> paramValueList.getChildren().remove(root));

    return root;
}
```

Personally, I prefer this approach as it's safer, more flexible, and in my opinion clearer. But it is also more work than the first approach.